# Jetpack Compose Navigation throwing exception in release build if minify has enabled

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

Getting the below exception on the release version but working fine on debug build.

navigation version which is used

`implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination screen_dashboard is not a direct child of this NavGraph
       at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.kt:72)
       at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.kt:49)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.kt:1161)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1086)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:100)
       at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:118)
       at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:67)
```

tried to update the proguard-rules.pro but still getting the exception

`-keep class androidx.navigation.** { *; }`